# prestashop add tips for error mesage

Tags: php, prestashop

my prestashop module return some error messages and i get more questions about solve this errors i want add some tips for this errors.
when insert new product to database this code line return error mesage for example "name is empty"

```
`$lang_field_error = $productObj->validateFieldsLang(self::UNFRIENDLY_ERROR, true)`
```

*and i show errror msg look like this*

```
$error_tmp = ($field_error !== true ? $field_error : '') . (isset($lang_field_error) && $lang_field_error !== true ? $lang_field_error : '') . Db::getInstance()->getMsgError();
                if ($error_tmp != '') {
                    $this->error_msg[] = sprintf(
                        Tools::displayError('Product (ID: %1$s) cannot be saved. %2$s'),
                        (isset($product['id_product']) && !empty($product['id_product'])) ? Tools::safeOutput(
                            $product['id_product']
                        ) : 'No ID',
                        $error_tmp
                    );
                }
```

**$productObj->validateFieldsLang() this method comes from ObjectModel class**

```
    public function validateFieldsLang($die = true, $error_return = false)
{
    foreach ($this->def['fields'] as $field => $data) {
        if (empty($data['lang'])) {
            continue;
        }

        $values = $this->$field;

        // If the object has not been loaded in multilanguage, then the value is the one for the current language of the object
        if (!is_array($values)) {
            $values = array($this->id_lang => $values);
        }

        // The value for the default must always be set, so we put an empty string if it does not exists
        if (!isset($values[Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')])) {
            $values[Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')] = '';
        }

        foreach ($values as $id_lang => $value) {
            if (is_array($this->update_fields) && empty($this->update_fields[$field][$id_lang])) {
                continue;
            }

            $message = $this->validateField($field, $value, $id_lang);
            if ($message !== true) {
                if ($die) {
                    throw new PrestaShopException($message);
                }
                return $error_return ? $message : false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

and return error msg for display, 
for example if error msg is "the name field is empty" i want add error tip look like "you products name cannot be empty "

**I must catch errors kind,(not from string) Can anyone Help me?**

Answer (score 0):

In file /classes/ObjectModel.php file, you will see a function named validateField() that is being called from the code you shared.

You need to add conditions in this function to change the returned error. You can add conditions to indicate that the current controller is your controller or something similar.

You can use the following code to get the name of current controller:

```
Tools::getValue('controller');
```